# Does moving a file in SVN delete its revision history?

Tags: svn, revision

I realize this might be an easy question that I may have overlooked in the documentation, but I didn't find any other questions like this.

When I move a file, or in my case a whole ton of files (I moving everything into trunk from repo root) do I lose revision history? My thought is it looks a lot like it's deleting and adding files and I would therefore lose history. Thoughts?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No.

`svn move` is equivalent to `svn copy`, and then `svn delete`.  Copied files share their history with the originals.

Answer (score 8):

You won't lose anything:

From `svn help mv`:

> Note:  this subcommand is equivalent to a 'copy' and 'delete'.

Therefore, from `svn help copy`:

> copy (cp): Duplicate something in working copy or repository, **remembering history.**

Answer (score 6):

If you remembered to use `svn mv` then history will be preserved.

But if you manually worked with `cp`, `svn delete` and `svn add` then history will **not** be preserved.